# Spotify Android SDK - How to obtain playlist position of current track?

Tags: android, spotify

I'm using the Spotify Android SDK to play Spotify tracks from my app. Before playing a track, I would like to have the option to store the 'state' of the track that is currently set in Spotify.

I figured out how to obtain the track uri and the playback position via `PlayerApi.getPlayerState()` (https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/app-remote-lib/docs/com/spotify/android/appremote/api/PlayerApi.html#getPlayerState--).

In case the current track is played as part of a playlist, I can obtain the playlist uri via `PlayerApi.subscribeToPlayerContext()` (https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/app-remote-lib/docs/com/spotify/android/appremote/api/PlayerApi.html#subscribeToPlayerContext--)

However I don't see any method to get the index of the track in the current playlist. As `PlayerApi.skipToIndex()` seems to allow to play a specific track of a playlist, I would have expected that there is also a method to obtain the current playlist index, but I can't see any.

Comment: Just a guess, but because playlists can be modified, how do you know that the position you store is still valid? i.e. they add 3 songs to the beginning of the playlist, your index is now off by 3. Perhaps they are only expecting you to store the index yourself for a short period?